# How do you make a two dimensional array of user specified value?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I declare a two dimensional array of size n by n which the user gives?
For example, why would this work:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int *array = new int[n];
//no errors
```

but this would not:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int *array = new int[n][n];
// these errors:
//error: array size in new-expression must be constant
//error: the value of 'n' is not usable in a constant expression
//note: 'int n' is not const
```

Is it possible to have a two dimensional array of row and column size n or would you have to use a vector?
Thanks!

Comment: If you say, … does not work, please include the error message always

Comment: I'm wondering which is more important in principle, the amount of memory being allocated dynamically or the dimensionality...

Answer (score 2):

Do it with a vector, like this:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
auto matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/zsOiUTvCbxAGmK6d

---

There is also a [`std::valarray` template](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/) which is similar functionality as `std::vector`, but has interesting extra functionality, which can be useful in case of matrix.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Vq141QpEWcWoUxM

Comment: I was gonna say use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` but there are about a billion ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Why would you do std:: when you can do "using namespace std;"

Comment: habit from coding standard in project I'm working on.

Comment: don't do it with `new` `delete` since soon or later it will end with code hard to maintain and a memory leak.

Comment: @David: Because you cannot use it in header files anyway, so why not just be consistent everywhere in your code? I also think the extra `std::` make the code more readable, because the standard-library components stand out visually.

Comment: @David Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oh I thought you could use it in header files if you just put using namespace std; I am still relatively new to programming and c++

Comment: @David: You technically can, but it's considered bad practice, as it may break other parts of the code in an unexpected way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/3313064 for an excellent answer on this topic.

Comment: It should be noted this creates a vector of vectors and not a two-dimensional arrays. These have different performance characteristics, different amounts of memory requirements, and different memory layouts. E.g., a vector of vectors requires every vector within it to be allocated and initialized. It is something of a waste to initialize memory management data for multiple vectors when they will all be identical lengths.

Comment: Yes, but this is answer for newbie, so writing about better solutions is pointless.

Comment: @MarekR: You do not have to write about newer solutions to include a note that this is not really a two-dimensional array and has issues that the student ought to learn about as they gain experience. Furthermore, Stack Overflow is a durable repository of knowledge, not just a homework-help site.

Comment: Oops, “better solutions,” not “newer solutions.”

Answer (score 1):

To create a multidimensional array, you would have to write this:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int **array = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[n];
}
```

And don't forget to delete it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    delete[] array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

But current c++ best practice is to never allocate or deallocate memory in application code, meaning you should use a `std::vector` or some other container class.

Comment: Would this create an array of n dimensions?  Sorry, I wasn't specific enough, I meant I wanted to create a 2D array or size n by n.

Comment: No, this array has only 2 dimensions. The code just allocates memory for each first-level entry.

Comment: It should be noted this creates an array of pointers to arrays of `int`. While this can be addressed syntactically like a two-dimensional array, it has different performance characteristics and different memory layouts. E.g., every reference to the array requires an extra memory reference to get a pointer, where a reference to an actual two-dimensional array would use an in-register calculation (which the compiler is often able to optimize in various ways). These differences might not matter much to a novice learning to program, but they should be aware of the issues as their experience grows.

Answer (score 1):

This answer differs in two points from most of the other answers:

- no raw pointer or memory allocation
- use a single contiguous (linear) block of memory

A common approach is using a **single linear block of memory** and storing the elements row after row or column after column ([Row- or column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)). Let us generalize a bit and say you want a 2D quantity of type `T` with the extents `N0` and `N1`. Then you can obtain the required memory by

```
std::vector<T> my_memory(N0*N1, T{});
```

Using a vector instead of a raw pointer has several advantages. For example, you can not forget to free the memory because the deconstructor cares about that automatically ([RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)). Another advantage is that the constructor called above fills the vector with copies of default-constructed `T` (instead of leaving the memory uninitialized).

Next, you can access the linear memory by using `vector`'s [member `operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) (or the [member function `at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) if you want bound checks). You probably want to use two indices `n0` and `n1` in the intervals [`0`, `N0`) and [`0`, `N1`), but the memory is linear and requires a single index. Hence you can introduce a helper function `index` in order to access your 2D quantity as, say,

```
my_memory[index(n0, n1)] = T(42);
```

To imagine how this could work consider a 3-by-2 matrix. In the given linear memory block you could arrange the elements like this:

```
         0           1           2           3           4           5
index(0, 0) index(0, 1) index(1, 0) index(1, 1) index(2, 0) index(2, 1)
```

In which case you would write

```
int index(int n0, int n1) {
  return n0 * N1 + n1;// (note that `n0` is multiplied by `N1`).
}
```

In general for `d` dimensions you would have (pseudo code)

```
int index(int(&n)[d]) {
  return n[0] * (N[1]*N[2]*...*N[d-1])
    + n[1] * (N[2]*N[3]*...*N[d-1])
    + ...
    + n[d-2] * (N[d-1])
    + n[d-1] * (1);
}
```

where the expressions in brackets are also called **pitches**.

If you put all that logic in a class, is becomes very simple to use. Here is an example for inspiration ([online demo with `N = 4`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a55e4f39daabc2d)):

```
#include <cassert>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class Quantity2d {
 private:
  std::size_t Ns_[2];
  std::vector<T> data_;
 public:
  Quantity2d(int N0, int N1)
  : Ns_{std::size_t(N0), std::size_t(N1)}
  , data_()
  {
    assert(N0 > 0);
    assert(N1 > 0);
    data_.resize(size(), T{});
  }

  constexpr size_t size() const { return Ns_[0] * Ns_[1]; }

  constexpr int N0() const { return int(Ns_[0]); }
  constexpr int N1() const { return int(Ns_[1]); }

  constexpr size_t pitch0() const { return Ns_[1]; }
  constexpr size_t pitch1() const { return std::size_t(1); }

  constexpr size_t ind(int n0, int n1) const {
    assert(n0 >= 0 && n0 < N0());
    assert(n1 >= 0 && n1 < N1());
    return std::size_t(n0) * pitch0() + std::size_t(n1) * pitch1();
  }

  T& operator()(int n1, int n2) {
    return data_[ind(n1, n2)];
  }

  constexpr const T& operator()(int n1, int n2) const {
    return data_[ind(n1, n2)];
  }
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Quantity2d<T>& q) {
  int N0 = q.N0();
  int N1 = q.N1();
  for(int i=0; i<N0; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j<N1; ++j) {
      os << i << "\t" << j << "\t" << q(i, j) << "\n";
    }
  }
  return os;
}

int main() {
  int N = 0;
  std::cout << "please enter size per dimension "
    << "(WARNING: matrix will be printed on screen): "
    << std::flush;
  std::cin >> N;

  if(N >= 1) {
    std::cout << "I understood. So let's do " << N << "x" << N << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cerr << "You failed. Next time try with N >= 1." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  Quantity2d<double> matrix(N, N);

  for(int i=0; i<matrix.N0(); ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j<matrix.N1(); ++j) {
      matrix(i, j) = double(i) * double(j);
    }
  }

  std::cout << matrix << std::flush;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a two dimensional array without using vectors like below.  This will work for all the types.

```
template <typename T> 
T **Alloc2D( int nRows, int nCols)
{
      T **array2D;    
      array2D = new T*[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ )
          array2D[i] = new T [nCols];

      return array2D;
}

template <typename T>
void Free2D(T** dArray)
{
      delete [] *dArray;
      delete [] dArray;
}
```

But, the problem is memory management as it is a raw approach.

Instead, we can use vectors which is manageable like

```
typedef vector<vector<int>> ARRAY2D;
```

Comment: It should be noted this creates an array of pointers to arrays of `int`. While this can be addressed syntactically like a two-dimensional array, it has different performance characteristics and different memory layouts. E.g., every reference to the array requires an extra memory reference to get a pointer, where a reference to an actual two-dimensional array would use an in-register calculation (which the compiler is often able to optimize in various ways). These differences might not matter much to a novice learning to program, but they should be aware of the issues as their experience grows.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible:

```
int **marray = new int[n][n];
```

Comment: It is not wrong. `n` just need to be constant. A multidimensional array (as asked for) is possible. For dynamic size, e.g. `= calloc(n*n, sizeof(int))` would work

Comment: But n is not constant. The original question specifically talks about an n that was given by the user.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. See @jcarpenter2's answer, it is better indeed.